# stmt->get_result() doesn't complete

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have a php code with echos to check where it stops (it doesn't crash but stops sending echos and doesn't work as expected)

```
$stmt=$conexion->prepare("SELECT Email, MaxActiv FROM `Keys` WHERE ProdKey = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $varKey);
$stmt->execute();
echo "before";
$stmt->store_result();
echo "middle";
$resultado = $stmt->get_result();
echo "later";
$row = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
echo "then";
$aa = $row["Email"];
```

it stops before echo "later"; so it must fail on `get_result();`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible reasons:

1. Mysqlnd is not installed for your system, which makes get_result() unavailable. You have to install php-mysqlnd.
2. You cannot use both get_result() and store_result() at a time. Take out store_result call from the code.